# Can I avoid this casting in F#?

Tags: f#

The context of this question is a raytracer I am writing.

I have a Surface type which ideally I want it an abstract base class which NoSurface and Lambertian inherit from.

However when I have this hierarchy I have the following problem:

```
    let closestIntersection : bool*LineParameter*Surface = 
    match allIntersectionsWithRealSolutions with 
        | [] -> (false,0.0f, NoSurface(0UL,NotHitable(),Material(Vector3.Zero)))
        | x::xs -> List.reduce (fun smallest current -> smallestIntersection smallest current) allIntersectionsWithRealSolutions
```

This throws a **compiler error** since the type it binds the return type to is NoSurface, even when specifying the type as Surface.

This fixed the issue:

```
    let closestIntersection : bool*LineParameter*Surface = 
    match allIntersectionsWithRealSolutions with 
        | [] -> (false,0.0f, NoSurface(0UL,NotHitable(),Material(Vector3.Zero)) :> Surface)
        | x::xs -> List.reduce (fun smallest current -> smallestIntersection smallest current) allIntersectionsWithRealSolutions
closestIntersection
```

But the cast `:>` costs me 25ms according to BenchmarkDotNet compared to the Solution of defining Surface as a (non abstract) class and simply returning it instead!

Can I somehow avoid explicit casting and have the desired hierarchy of Surface being and abstract class?

Comment: Tried `upcast`?

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? I am kind of new to F#

Comment: @FuleSnabel Ive tried `| [] -> (false,0.0f, (upcast NoSurface(0UL,NotHitable(),Material(Vector3.Zero)) : Surface))` and yes you were right! Its a lot faster! Also around 25 ms. Thanks! Why is this difference in performance?

Comment: Tried a bit locally but I can't reproduce the performance loss you see. It's probably because I don't have the correct type definitions. For issues like this I recommend using a tool like dotPeek to see what your code is compiled into. Sometimes one need to go into IL to see it.

Comment: Well Im running a this in a very recursive context. Maybe casting during such a scenario has performance implications? If you could explain why upcast is faster than :> I would give you the correct answer tick.

Comment: If you could share the code where you see performance hit I would be able to explain it. When trying to reproduce it locally I failed because it was to simplistic.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Sure! The file is located here https://github.com/geoeo/Raytracer/blob/master/raytracer/Surface.fs

Answer (score 3):

You could try to solve the same problem using discriminating unions, which would be the more 'functional' way, since you're using F#?. Although i'm somewhat sure this approach might be a bit slower. But then, if you're after maximum performance a managed language is not the best pick to start with.
Find a good unions explanation at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/

so something like this.

```
type Intersectable =
    | Sphere of center:Point3 * radius:float
    | Triangle of v0:Point3 * v1:Point3 * v2:Point3
    | MeshTriangle of faceIndex:int * mesh:Mesh
    | Instance of Intersectable * Matrix.Matrix4x4
    | Plane of normal:Vec3 * pointOnPlane: Point3
```

shared/common functionality can be tackled by using common data parts which your functions act on, you might have:

```
type Shape = {
    geometry: Intersectable
    material: Material }
```

Comment: Thank you for the type definitions. I was thinking of something like this. I might branch into this. If its slower well see ;) I disagree with the earlier sentiment though. There are shades of grey here. Raytracing is (in my opinion) a very functional problem. So I wanted to try F#. But just because I am using F# doesnt mean I want to run bad/slow code. The ability of HoF and list comprehensions has been really helpful.